# SQLAlchemy difference between contains_eager and joinedload

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

what is the difference in SQLAlchemy between `contains_eager` and `joinedload`. 
I read the [manual](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#routing-explicit-joins-statements-into-eagerly-loaded-collections) about contains_eager, and [manual](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#joined-eager-loading) about joinedload too. They are both can be used for loading one-to-many related rows, or many-to-one.

they are generating the same sql:

```
query = session.query(User).\
    outerjoin(adalias, User.addresses).\
    options(contains_eager(User.addresses, alias=adalias)).all()

...

SELECT
    users.user_id AS users_user_id,
    users.user_name AS users_user_name,
    adalias.address_id AS adalias_address_id,
    adalias.user_id AS adalias_user_id,
    adalias.email_address AS adalias_email_address,
    (...other columns...)
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN email_addresses AS email_addresses_1
ON users.user_id = email_addresses_1.user_id


>>> jack = session.query(User).\
... options(joinedload(User.addresses)).\
... filter_by(name='jack').all()

SELECT
    addresses_1.id AS addresses_1_id,
    addresses_1.email_address AS addresses_1_email_address,
    addresses_1.user_id AS addresses_1_user_id,
    users.id AS users_id, users.name AS users_name,
    users.fullname AS users_fullname,
    users.password AS users_password
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses AS addresses_1
    ON users.id = addresses_1.user_id
WHERE users.name = ?
['jack']
```

Can anybody show more particular code examples?

Comment: For a practical example, please [refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67578848/), and modify the `.options(contains_eager(Child.toys))` to `.options(joinedload(Child.toys))` and see that `Child.toys` is no longer being populated as a filtered subset.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't forget many to many and one to one. The difference is that with `contains_eager()` you instruct SQLA about an existing join or joins that should be used to populate a relationship. This way you can also [populate using a filtered subset](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/queryguide/relationships.html#using-contains-eager-to-load-a-custom-filtered-collection-result).

`joinedload()` on the other hand goes to great lengths to make the joins required for populating entirely transparent and they should not affect the outcome of the original query, as is explained in [The Zen of Joined Eager Loading](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html#the-zen-of-joined-eager-loading). In other words you cannot use the joined relations for filtering etc.

Comment: What is worth to mention: You SHOULDN'T use `contains_eager()` or `joinedload` for 1-N or N-N relations. It's because SQL result produces multiplication of data on one or two sides.  For 1-N or N-N relations is better to use `selectinload` or `subqueryload`.

Comment: True, and of the two usually selectin, but those do not allow (to my knowledge) filtering the related entities that populate the relationship in SQLA. So it's a kind of a "pick your poison" situation in case you need to do that. Hopefully the filtered set is then small enough that the duplication on the 1-side does not matter much.

Comment: Agree, for small amounts of data usually it doesn't matter, however I was a witness when someone performed several joinedloads and DB returned output 25 times bigger than entire database :)

Comment: That is awesome in its own way. In a previous job we had some fun with accidental cross joins...

Comment: For completeness, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440296/how-does-the-sqlalchemy-loading-methods-work) compares the other loaders and the answer goes a bit into the problems with using `joinedload`.