# How does the sqlalchemy loading methods work?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I read documentation, but explanation there was insufficient. So I decided to ask for help here.

What is the difference between the sqlalchemy load methods: joinedload, lazyload, defaultload and subqueryload? Especially difference between joinedload and subqueryload.
I would be glad to see as simple an explanation as possible of the differences. Thanks

Comment: It most certainly is anything but insufficient. Verbose, perhaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `lazyload` does not load immediately but waits for first access
- `subqueryload` and `joinedload` both load immediately the related collection, but by emitting different SQL. Even if the result is the same for both mode, there might be a large performance difference.

Assume a class A that hold a list of children towards both B and C:

```
class A:
    b_list = relationship(B, lazy='joined')
    c_list = relationship(C, lazy='joined')

class B:
    a_id = Column(ForeignKey('a.id'))

class C:
    a_id = Column(ForeignKey('a.id'))
```

If you set both b_list and c_list as `joinedload`, then the following sql will be emitted (or similar):

```
SELECT ... FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id
LEFT JOIN C ON C.a_id = A.id
WHERE ...
```

If there is 1000 elements in both B and C, 1 000 000 rows will be returned, then sqlalchemy will sort out duplicates in python space. With large numbers and more relationships, it may even make your database or your application run out of memory.

`subqueryload` shouldn't have this problem, since all relations are loaded separately via a subquery. I'm not totally sure of the difference between `subqueryload` and `selectinload`, but according to the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html#subquery-eager-loading), `subqueryload` is a legacy loader, and is superseded by `selectinload`.

For what it's worth, in our project, we use the following policy (that is actually automated):

- load single element relationships with `joinedload`.
- load collections with `selectinload`.

Comment: As for the difference between `subqueryload` and `selectinload`, the first emits sub-selects (`SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... lhs JOIN rhs ON ... WHERE ...) AS anon_1 JOIN rhs ON ...), while the latter generates two separate queries, first to query list of `lhs` and then generates a second query for `rhs` with `WHERE rhs.lhs_id IN (...)` for all the `lhs.id` that got matched.