# SQLAlchemy 2.x: Eagerly load joined collection query

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

### Context

With SQLAlchemy 2.x, how to eagerly load a joined collection?

Let's say we have the following models `Parent` and `Child`:

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))

    children: Mapped[List["Child"]] = relationship(
        back_populates="parent", cascade="all, delete-orphan"
    )

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Parent(id={self.id!r}, name={self.name!r})"

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))

    parent_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("parent.id"))
    parent: Mapped["Parent"] = relationship(back_populates="children")

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Child(id={self.id!r}, name={self.name!r})"
```

And I would like to get the `Parent` that has a `Child` with `id` equal to 1. And populate the result `parent.children` with all its children.

IOW, if our `parent` and `child` tables are populated with:

```
parent
id  name
1   p1
2   p2
```

```
child
id  name  parent_id
1   c1    1
2   c2    1
3   c2    1
4   c3    1
5   c4    2
```

I would like to see the query result object:

```py
result = <query parent whose children has id == 1>
print(result)
>>> Parent(id=1, name='p1')

print(result.children)
>>> [
        Child(id=1, name='c1'),
        Child(id=2, name='c2'),
        Child(id=3, name='c3'),
        Child(id=4, name='c4'),
    ]
```

### Test case 1

```py
stmt = select(Parent).join(Parent.children).where(Child.id == 1)
```

Generates the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT parent.id, parent.name 
FROM parent JOIN child ON parent.id = child.parent_id 
WHERE child.id = 1
```

Which looks great, but since I don't tell sqlalchemy to eagerly load `children`, when accessing the result scalar object (`parent.children`), I get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)
```

### Test case 2

```py
stmt = select(Parent).options(joinedload(Parent.children)).where(Child.id == 1)
```

Generates the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT parent.id, parent.name, child_1.id AS id_1, child_1.name AS name_1, child_1.parent_id 
FROM parent JOIN child AS child_1 ON parent.id = child_1.parent_id, child 
WHERE child.id = 1
```

Which is not what we're looking for, notice `child` now appears in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67578639/flask-sqlalchemy-filter-objects-in-relationship-for-each-object/) may be relevant.

Comment: @metatoaster thanks for the reference. It seems relevant! Adding `contains_eager` to my query didn't fully solved it. I now have `.children` populated, but only with a single `Child`. I would like to see all Child(id=1) siblings as well, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was kind of suprised but joining with an alias appears to work but it seems like a footgun for later.  I'm kind of a big fan of subqueries and that might be more flexible later on and maybe even faster.

I did not test this with async but I think it should work.

```
2023-05-27 15:44:06,791 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-05-27 15:44:06,809 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT parents.id, parents.name, childs_1.id AS id_1, childs_1.name AS name_1, childs_1.parent_id 
FROM parents JOIN childs AS childs_2 ON parents.id = childs_2.parent_id LEFT OUTER JOIN childs AS childs_1 ON parents.id = childs_1.parent_id 
WHERE childs_2.id = %(id_2)s
2023-05-27 15:44:06,809 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00066s] {'id_2': 1}
2023-05-27 15:44:06,814 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
2023-05-27 15:44:06,815 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-05-27 15:44:06,817 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT parents.id, parents.name, childs_1.id AS id_1, childs_1.name AS name_1, childs_1.parent_id 
FROM parents LEFT OUTER JOIN childs AS childs_1 ON parents.id = childs_1.parent_id 
WHERE parents.id IN (SELECT childs.parent_id 
FROM childs 
WHERE childs.id = %(id_2)s)
2023-05-27 15:44:06,817 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00018s] {'id_2': 1}
2023-05-27 15:44:06,819 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
```

```py
import sys
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    String,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
    ForeignKey,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session, aliased, relationship, joinedload


Base = declarative_base()


username, password, db = sys.argv[1:4]


engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=True)


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parents"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    childs = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'childs'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id'), nullable=False)
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="childs")


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

parents = [line.split()[:2] for line in """
1   p1
2   p2
""".splitlines() if line.strip()]

# Changed child names to be consistent.
childs = [line.split()[:3] for line in """
1   c1    1
2   c2    1
3   c3    1
4   c4    1
5   c5    2
""".splitlines() if line.strip()]

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add_all([Parent(id=int(parent[0]), name=parent[1]) for parent in parents])
    session.add_all([Child(id=int(child[0]), name=child[1], parent_id=int(child[2])) for child in childs])
    session.commit()

def test_results(parents):
    assert len(parents) == 1
    assert len(parents[0].childs) == 4
    assert list(sorted([child.id for child in parents[0].childs])) == [1, 2, 3, 4]

# using aliased to prevent join conflict
with Session(engine) as session:
    c2 = aliased(Child)
    q = select(Parent).join(c2, Parent.id == c2.parent_id).where(c2.id == 1).options(joinedload(Parent.childs))
    parents = [parent for parent in session.scalars(q).unique()]
    test_results(parents)

# subquery
with Session(engine) as session:
    parents = list(session.scalars(select(Parent).where(Parent.id.in_(select(Child.parent_id).where(Child.id == 1))).options(joinedload(Parent.childs))).unique())
    test_results(parents)
```

Comment: Another great option is to use `selectinload` and then you don't have to worry about the loader `JOIN` messing with your query.

Comment: Super! I really like the alias based solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer @IanWilson wrote is quite excellent, but to expand on the subquery case and expand on his comment about `selectinload`, I decided to also contribute an answer.

If you know for a fact that a child will only have one parent, the `IN` comparison can be fully avoided by using the standard `==`, like the following example:

```py
with Session(engine) as session:
    # The parent with Child.id == 1, which contains it plus its siblings
    query = (
        select(Parent)
        .join(Parent.children)  # plurals are hard (childs isn't quite right)
        .where(Parent.id ==
            select(Child.parent_id)
            .where(Child.id == 1)
            .scalar_subquery()  # to ensure a single result returned here
        )
        .options(selectinload(Parent.children))
    )
    result = session.execute(query).unique().all()
    print(result)
```

Do note that there is an additional function call attached to the subquery - `.scalar_subquery()` is needed otherwise this `SAWarning` is triggered:

```text
SAWarning: implicitly coercing SELECT object to scalar subquery; please use the .scalar_subquery() method to produce a scalar subquery.
```

Also in my example I used `selectinload` (from `sqlalchemy.orm`) as an option as suggested in the answer I referenced to show what would happen - the following queries would instead be emitted:

```text
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT parent.id, parent.name 
FROM parent JOIN child ON parent.id = child.parent_id 
WHERE parent.id = (SELECT child.parent_id 
FROM child 
WHERE child.id = ?)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[generated in 0.00014s] (1,)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT child.parent_id AS child_parent_id, child.id AS child_id, child.name AS child_name 
FROM child 
WHERE child.parent_id IN (?)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[generated in 0.00016s] (1,)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:ROLLBACK
```

Splitting the query up may be necessary - as query using the either `contains_eager` and `joinedload` option will result in a `JOIN` query of some kind which would result in all values from the left hand side (in this case the `Parent`) be repeated for every `Child` rows that gets returned by the query.  Not too much of a huge deal in this small example, but this can get *very* expensive quickly if there are many columns in `Parent` (and worse if they are very large columns) and/or there are many `Child` rows that will be returned by the query due to how a join query involves doing a Cartesian product (multiplication) between the two sides of the join, thus this strategy is generally [not recommended for 1-N or N-to-N relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187867/sqlalchemy-difference-between-contains-eager-and-joinedload#comment109020394_50189556).  A funny [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187867/sqlalchemy-difference-between-contains-eager-and-joinedload#comment109021002_50189556) (also from that thread) about why doing the join query might be bad, "I was a witness when someone performed several joinedloads and DB returned output 25 times bigger than entire database :)".

For some additional background, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56440793/) goes into a bit more details about `joinedload` vs `selectinload`; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187867/sqlalchemy-difference-between-contains-eager-and-joinedload) discusses the difference between `joinedload` and `contains_eager` as to the difference between them, and [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67578639/flask-sqlalchemy-filter-objects-in-relationship-for-each-object) on the latter.