# Flask sqlalchemy filter objects in relationship for each object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

**How to filter objects in relationship in one command?**

Example filter: I have list of *childrens* and every *children* has *toys*. Show me how to filter each childs toys, so that list *child.toys* contains only red toys.

```
class Child(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40))
    toys = db.relationship('Toy', lazy='dynamic')


class Toy(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    color = db.Column(db.String(40))
    child_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('child.id') )
```

| Child id | Child name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | First |
| 2 | Second |

| Toy id | Toy color | Toy child_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Blue | 1 |
| 2 | Red | 1 |
| 3 | Orange | 2 |
| 4 | Red | 2 |

Desired output in python list:

| Child id | Child name | Toy id | Toy color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First | 2 | Red |
| 2 | Second | 4 | Red |

*Edit:*
this table will be printed by:

```
for child in filtered_children: 
    for toy in child.toys:
        print(f'{child.id} {child.name} {toy.id} {toy.color}')
```

Dynamic Relationship Loaders provides correct result, but you have to iterate like this in for loop:

```
children = Child.query.all()
for child in children:
    child.toys = child.toys.filter_by(color='Red')
len( children[0].toys ) #should by one
len( children[1].toys ) #should by one
```

**Is there a way how to filter objects from relationship without for loop?**

Edit:
Reformulated question: *Is there a way to apply the filter at the outer query such that no additional filtering need to be done inside the for loop such that each child.toys attribute for each child in the loop will only contain Red toys?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>This answer has been updated for SQLAlchemy 2.0 to reflect the [2.0 style](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/glossary.html#term-2.0-style) while maintaining the original intent of [this prior revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67578848/10) which was written in the 1.x style.</sub>

---

Since it appears you already configured some rudimentary relationship that allowed the usage of [join conditions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/join_conditions.html), the next step is simply to actually use [joins](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/select.html#joins) to bring the relationships that were defined together.

My example below uses SQLAlchemy directly, so you may need to adapt the references to those specific to Flask-SQLALchemy (e.g. instead of creating a session from the engine context, you may instead use `db.session` as per the guidance provided via its [quickstart](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/); also the `Child` and `Toy` classes I used inherit from a common local `Base` class for the same reason, otherwise the same principles introduced below should be commonly applicable).

First, import and set up the classes - to keep this generalized, I will be using `sqlalchemy` directly as noted:

```
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, String
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, Session
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column, relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import contains_eager

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(40))
    toys = relationship('Toy')

class Toy(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'toy'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    color: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(40))
    child_id = mapped_column(ForeignKey('child.id'))
```

Note that the `Child.toys` relationship construct does not need any other extra arguments, given that the specified `'dynamic'` style of loading is incompatible with the query desired.

Then set up the engine and add your data provided from your question:

```
children = [line.split()[:2] for line in """
1   First
2   Second
""".splitlines() if line.strip()]

toys = [line.split()[:3] for line in """
1   Blue     1
2   Red      1
3   Orange   2
4   Red      2
""".splitlines() if line.strip()]

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add_all(
        [Child(id=int(i), name=j) for i, j in children])
    session.add_all(
        [Toy(id=int(i), color=j, child_id=int(k)) for i, j, k in toys])
    session.commit()
```

With the data added, we can see that in the documentation for loading relationships from SQLAlchemy, there is a [rather comprehensive set of relationship loading techniques](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html).  As the amount of data being dealt with is small and to keep the example straightforward, the `contains_eager` from the list of [relationship loader API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html#relationship-loader-api) may be suitable one for your use case, as it states "that the given attribute should be eagerly loaded from columns stated manually in the query." Moreover, as per the example provided with [the documentation for this loader](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html#using-contains-eager-to-load-a-custom-filtered-collection-result), it was demonstrated that the collection defined by the relationship will contain only the filtered entries, and not any other entries that are in fact associated with the collection (for another explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50189556/)).

So let's see it in action:

```
with Session(engine) as session:
    query = (select(Child)
        .join(Child.toys)
        .filter(Toy.color == 'Red')
        .options(contains_eager(Child.toys))
    )
    filtered_children = session.scalars(query).unique().all()
```

This query ensures that the `toys` relationship declared through the `Child` is joined with the query, and that we also filter by `"Red"` toys, with the option to indicate that `Child.toys` should be "eager loaded from columns stated manually in the query" such that it will become available through each of the returned `child` object, without needing additional selects triggered on-demand.

Now, see that your most recent desired for loop over `filtered_children` and their `toys` produce your desired output:

```
for child in filtered_children:
    for toy in child.toys:
        print(f'{child.id} {child.name} {toy.id} {toy.color}')
```

The following output should be produced ([gist of all the code](https://gist.github.com/metatoaster/fc63226e644a22235423803f85e3a8ab)):

```text
1 First 2 Red
2 Second 4 Red
```

If we had logging enabled, we will see that the following output that indicates the `SELECT` statement that was issued by SQLAlchemy's engine:

```text
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT toy.id, toy.color, toy.child_id, child.id AS id_1, child.name 
FROM child JOIN toy ON child.id = toy.child_id 
WHERE toy.color = ?
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[generated in 0.00014s] ('Red',)
DEBUG:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:Col ('id', 'color', 'child_id', 'id_1', 'name')
DEBUG:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:Row (2, 'Red', 1, 1, 'First')
DEBUG:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:Row (4, 'Red', 2, 2, 'Second')
```

Note that only a single `SELECT ... JOIN` query was done and no additional queries were made for each of the `Child`.  While this may appear to avoid perceived performance impact of having to do manual queries later (especially being only loader that will ensure the relationships have the filter applied eagerly), this *can* have real impact if there are many columns in both `Child` and `Toy` and that many instances are returned, as this strategy effectively forces a Cartesian product and may potentially result in more than expected amount of data being passed from the database to the application, so this is something to be mindful of.

Comment: can you make it so that len(child.toys) == 1 ? To access toys trough child object.

Comment: In my question was line: "len( children[0].toys ) #should by one"    . Provided solution just did not match this. I am VERY THANKFULL for your answer, but it did not meet "test" code that was provided. I also appended code that does what I need, but it does it in for loop. Maybe my "Desired output in python list" was confusing. So....:  *How to apply the filter at the outer query such that no additional filtering need to be done inside the for loop such that each child.toys attribute for each child in the loop will only contain Red toys?*

Comment: @AlbertMyšák well, is the updated solution what you were after? Do realize you may need to update the `toys` attribute `db.relationship` setup as I noted.

Comment: I did not see your edit. Works. I have spent 7 hours in documentation. Bounty is yours.